# How to create dynamic variables in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

The real scenario, want to get a resource id of sqs in AWS, which will be returned after the execution of a playbook. So, using this variable in files to configure the application.

Persisting variables from one playbook to another

checking out the documentation, modules like set_fact and register have scope only for that specific host. There are many purpose of using the variables from one host to another.

Alternatives I can think of:

1. using Command module and echoing the variables to a file. Later, using the variable file using vars section or include.
2. Setting the env variables and then accessing it but this will be difficult.

So what is the solution?

Comment: To be sure of your question, you mean dynamic variables that are either pulled from a host or created during the course of a playbook run, correct?  If so, you should edit your question as otherwise this sounds like something that could be solved by linking you to the variables documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're gathering facts, you can access hostvars via the normal jinja2 + variable lookup:

e.g.

```
- hosts: serverA.example.org
  gather_facts: True
  ...
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        taco_tuesday: False
```

and then, if this has run, on another host:

```
- hosts: serverB.example.org
  ...
  tasks:

    - debug: var="{{ hostvars['serverA.example.org']['ansible_memtotal_mb'] }}"

    - debug: var="{{ hostvars['serverA.example.org']['taco_tuesday'] }}"
```

Keep in mind that if you have multiple Ansible control machines (where you call `ansible` and `ansible-playbook` from), you should take advantage of the fact that Ansible can store its [facts/variables in a cache](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching) (currently Redis and json), that way the control machines are less likely to have different hostvars.  With this, you could set your control machines to use a file in a shared folder (which has its risks -- what if two control machines are running on the same host at the same time?), or set/get facts from a Redis server.

For my uses of Amazon data, I prefer to just fetch the resource each time using a tag/metadata lookup.  I wrote an [Ansible plugin](https://github.com/tfishersp/aws_tag) that allows me to do this a little more easily as I prefer this to thinking about hostvars and run ordering (but your mileage may vary).

Comment: I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Moreover I use set_facts and the scope of this is host level. So when I use this in other hosts, should use with jinja 2 template. It works if the set_fact is retrieved in the same playbook but when I use in different playbook, it is not persisted. Is the implementation is wrong or should I use redis for fact caching to persist across playbooks

Comment: This is the officially supported way to do it.  Look into "fact-caching" and enable it in your ansible.cfg if you have not already: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables On The Command Line: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line

```
ansible-playbook release.yml --extra-vars "version=1.23.45 other_variable=foo"
```

You can use local connection to run playbook = get variable and apply it to another playbook:

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  - shell: ansible-playbook -i ...
    register: sqs_id
  - shell: ansible-playbook -i ... -e "sqs_id={{sqs_id.stdout}}"
```

Also delegation might be useful in this scenario:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation

Also you can store output in the local file and use (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation): 
     - name: take a sqs id
        local_action: command cat ~/sqs_id

PS:

I don't understand why you can't write complex playbook where will be included many roles that will share variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can write "common" variables to a `host_vars` or `group_vars` this way all the servers has access to it.

Another way may be to create a custom `ansible module/lookup plugin` to hide all the boilerplate code and get an easy and flexible access to the variables you need.

Comment: The need for this is,  var A is a fact of host A, so I need this var A in playbook while executing host  B. So any alternatives?

Comment: You need a shared storage that would keep your variables for undetermined amount of time. So that you can run  a play A today and play B tomorrow. you can easily and secure store them on AWS S3. and create a simple ansible module/ lookup plugin to access this information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with azure DevOps pipelines.
I created VM:s with terraform, ssh-keys and windows username/password was generated by terraform and stored it in a KeyVault.

So I then needed to query KeyVault before running Ansible on all created VM:s. I ended up using Azure python SDK to get all secrets. I also generate an inventory file and a host_vars folder with a file for each VM.

The actual play-book is now very basic and does the job perfectly. All variables for terraform and ansible is in a json file. And the python script is less than 30 lines.